# Subtracting one column from another in VBA, getting mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba, subtraction

Hi I'm trying to create a VBA code that fills the entire column G values with Column E - Column F (so E2-F2 = G2) but I keep getting mismatch error. The values start from the second row and I have created a loop to run down the columns.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub RemainingHours()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2    
With Sheets("Opt")
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(5, i).Value)
   Cells(7, i).Value = Cells(6, i).Value - Cells(5, i).Value
    i = i + 1
    Wend
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you switched the row and column in the Cells function.  Try Cells(i, #) on all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping you could try using Evaluate.

```
Sub RemainingHours()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Res As Variant

    With Sheets("Opt")
        Set rng = .Range("E2", .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    
    Res = Evaluate(rng.Offset(, 1).Address & "-" & rng.Address)
    
    rng.Offset(, 2).Value = Res

End Sub
```

Comment: one note: You will want to use `WorkSheets("Opt").Evaluate` otherwise it will use the active sheet, which may or may not be the correct sheet.